React Native Expo- Firebase Google Authentication
I’m currently using React Native with Expo Go for my mobile app development. For user authentication, I’ve integrated Firebase and have successfully set up email verification and authentication. However, I am now looking to add Google Authentication to the mix.
When I initially set up Firebase, I didn’t explicitly choose Android or iOS; instead, I opted for a Web app configuration. This approach has worked well so far for email authentication, but I’m running into some issues finding a clear and comprehensive guide for adding Google Auth specifically with Expo Go.
I’ve scoured the internet and found various tutorials and snippets, but none seem to be tailored to my exact setup using Expo Go and Firebase with a Web app configuration. Most guides I find are either outdated, incomplete, or geared towards bare React Native projects rather than Expo Go.
Has anyone here successfully implemented Google Authentication in a similar setup? Any step-by-step guides, code snippets, or tips would be immensely appreciated. I’m particularly interested in how to configure the Firebase project and Expo app to work seamlessly together for Google Auth.
Thanks in advance for any help or insights!
I've been trying the following approach for Google Sign-In in my app:
const [request, response, promptAsync] = Google.useIdTokenAuthRequest({
  clientId: WEB_CLIENT_ID,
});

const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
const [user, setUser] = useState<FirebaseUser | null>(null);

useEffect(() => {
  if (response?.type === 'success') {
    const { id_token } = response.params;

    const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
    signInWithCredential(getAuth(), credential)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        setUser(userCredential.user);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Authentication error:', error);
      });
  }
}, [response]);

// The button for Google Sign-In
<Button
  title="Login with Google"
  disabled={!request}
  onPress={() => promptAsync()}
/>


However, when I try to sign in, the Google Sign-In window opens in the Android app, but I receive the following error message: "Access blocked: Authorization error."
You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.
You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with one or more Google validation rules.
Error 400: invalid_request
In my Google Console, I have configured the Authorized JavaScript Origins as https://auth.expo.io and also set the Authorized Redirect URIs to https://auth.expo.io/@name/app-slug.
